# FFMPEG mp4 input on android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, pipe, libav

I have been banging my head against the wall on this for a while now. I need to trim part of an mp4 file, using ffmpeg on android. I have ffmpeg compiled, linked, and I can confirm that it works as expected in my ndk calls. What I am running into is getting an mp4 file to ffmpeg in a protocol it can actually work with.

Right now, I have a Uri for the file that I get a ParcelFileDescriptor from. I pass its file descriptor to an ndk call that does all the ffmpeg processing using the pipe protocol. Issue: ffmpeg cannot read an mp4 over the pipe protocol, because it needs to seek back to the start once it finds the moov atom.

All I'm doing is remuxing the videos. I'm not doing any heavy work, or more complicated ffmpeg calls

Attempted solution: Set up custom AVio calls that open the descriptor as a file stream, and handle it that way. Issue: file descriptor from java is not seekable, it's more of a stream.

Possible solution: Preprocess videos to have the moov atom at the front. Issue: Not allowed, the files come from somewhere I cannot control.

Possible solution: Run one call to find all the file information, then another to actually remux the file. Issue: I don't know what I need to save from the first parse through to make this possible. Just the moov atom? Can I just replace the io object in the first call's inputFormatContext with a new one in the second call? Can I pass it two distinct file descriptors, both to the same file, and not have to make two ndk calls?

Any help or ideas you can offer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: My current plan is to pass three file descriptors, and just use a new one whenever ffmpeg wants to seek backwards. This is disgusting and I hate it, but it just might work. Will update on Monday with progress.

Comment: I was wrong in my post, FILE* are seekable, the issue was that ffmpeg uses some custom seek flags that Android really doesn't like. Writing a custom IO handler that just works as a filter for seek arguments works perfectly.